# More efficient, but readable alternative for this block of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Let's say I got 3 arrays, of which one is based on the other array, but I need to combine them into one.. I'm using forEach loops here to push items to the array but I feel like that's inefficient.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ["a", "b"];
const arr3 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

const obj = { 
  "1_a": [1, 2], 
  "1_b": [1, 2, 3], 
  "2_a": [1], 
  "2_b": [1, 2], 
  "3_a": [], 
  "3_b": [1, 2, 3] 
};

// push all the items to the temporary array - with forEach loops, 
// I feel like this logic can be made more readable and efficient
let tempArr = [];
arr1.forEach(i =>
  arr2.forEach(j => 
    tempArr.push(`${i}_${j}`)
  )
);
arr3.forEach(i => tempArr.push(i));

// loop over the temporary array to get the final result (logged below)
const arr = tempArr.map(key => {
  if (obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key].length > 1) return `update_${key}`;
  else return key;
});

// result
console.log(arr); // [ "update_1_a", "update_1_b", "2_a", "update_2_b", "3_a", "update_3_b" ]
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here with all the `forEach` pushes, I feel like there should be something like a nested map function..? Please help me out here..

I would like the following to happen:

- The values of arr2, are based on the loop of arr1 *(see example)*, these get combined with an underscore, pseudo: `arr1Item_arr2Item`, and this item gets pushed to the array.
- The values of arr3, just get looped and pushed
- The merged array gets looped, and in case the value of that item is in the object, and the array of that key is longer than 1, return `update_<arrItem>`, else just return `<arrItem>`

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz I did

Comment: What is the logic for constructing the final array? please explain.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I tried to explain it as clearly as possible, please have a look :)

Comment: What is the purpose of `arr3`? It's not being used, also you said "longer than 5", but according to the code you pasted, it's more like 1.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi arr3 has a purpose, all 3 arrs (arr1, arr2, arr3) get pushed to tempArr, and I would like to make that statement of forEach loop chaos better. As you can see the tempArr gets mapped, if the array which belongs to the object key is longer than 1, then return `update_<value>`, if not just return `<value>`

Comment: You are combining the values of `arr1` and `arr2` into `tempArr`, but simply adding the values of `arr3` at the end, is that what you want? Or do you want to combine all 3 into `tempArr`? Meaning that the 1st value in it should be `1_a_foo`.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi oh, sorry for being unclear, I just want to add those at the end yes

Comment: I see, well not sure if this is better but you can do this one liner:

`const tempArr = arr1.flatMap((v1) => (arr2.map((v2) => (\`${v1}_${v2}\`)))).concat(arr3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's any better, but it is a `reduce` and a `map`:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ["a", "b"];
const arr3 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

const obj = {
  "1_a": [1, 2],
  "1_b": [1, 2, 3],
  "2_a": [1],
  "2_b": [1, 2],
  "3_a": [],
  "3_b": [1, 2, 3],
};

const result = arr1.reduce(
  (a, c) =>
    (a.concat(
      arr2.map((y) => {
        const key = `${c}_${y}`;
        return obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key].length > 1
          ? `update_${key}`
          : key;
      })
    )),
  arr3
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not a big deal but no need for `(a = a.concat(`, `(a.concat(` is enough.

Comment: but what if there is a third array? (see post) :-)

Comment: Your reduce could use the third array as the starting point, but your example object has no `foo` `bar` or `baz` keys

Comment: @Anthony the edit you made works just fine, amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b'];

const obj = {
  '1_a': [1, 2],
  '1_b': [1, 2, 3],
  '2_a': [1],
  '2_b': [1, 2],
  '3_a': [],
  '3_b': [1, 2, 3]
};

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, a1) =>
  [...acc, ...arr2.map(a2 => {
    const keyCombined = `${a1}_${a2}`;
    return obj[keyCombined].length > 1
      ? `update_${keyCombined}`
      : `${keyCombined}`;
  })], []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `flatMap`:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ["a", "b"];
const arr3 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

const obj = {
  "1_a": [1, 2],
  "1_b": [1, 2, 3],
  "2_a": [1],
  "2_b": [1, 2],
  "3_a": [],
  "3_b": [1, 2, 3]
};

const result = [
  ...arr3,
  ...arr1
    .flatMap(a => arr2
      .map(b => {
        const key = `${a}_${b}`;
        return obj[key].length > 1 
          ? `update_${key}`
          : key;
      }))
]

console.log(result)
```